# Match From a Group of Words

Tags: ruby, regex

```
def has_word?
  text =~ /((Word1)|(Word2))/
end
```

This is what I do now and it works but I feel like there is a better ruby solution.  What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Why all the parentheses? `/Word1|Word2/` (or `/(Word1|Word2)/` if you need to capture the word) would be equivalent.

Comment: What about this solution seems problematic to you? The code is easy to read and it performs reasonably well (assuming no pathological input). What are you trying to improve?

Answer (score 1):

You may have some special situations to solve that aren't covered by your current approach.  Here are some common solutions for these types of

## Match regardless of case

```
/Word1|Word2/i
```

## Avoid finding a match in the middle of a word

```
/\b(Word1|Word2)\b/
```

## Match only the exact string

```
/^(Word1|Word2)$/
```

## Matching variable lists of strings

```
def get_match(strings)
  Regexp.new(strings.join("|"))
end

get_match(["Words", "word", "terrible", "one-way", "don't"])
get_match(["week", "month", "year"])
```

## Match longest word before shorter

```
def get_match(strings)
  Regexp.new(strings.sort.reverse.join("|"))
end

get_match(["Yes", "Day", "Yesterday", "Daytime"])
```